# nginx should not handle unicorn's request

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, nginx, rewrite

I have a server on which I have configured [Nginx](http://nginx.org/) and [Unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/), where Unicorn servers static pages. In my case I'm writing a rewrite rule in Nginx that, if a request comes to `mydomain.com` it should redirect to another domain, which is possible with following rule.

```
location / {
rewrite ^/$ yahoo.com;
}
```

Well, the above code is working fine for me, but when I write `mydomain.com/docs/web` in the address bar, Nginx throws 404 page. Basically, in my case Unicorn handles this request (when above Nginx code **does not** exist), and I want it so that Unicorn should handle this request when the above code exists in Nginx.

Comment: `location = /` instead of `location /`

Comment: yeah! tried with the same, but no luck.

Comment: What does the rest of your nginx config look like?